# Get the value of a sub array without looping twice?

Tags: php, oop, foreach, php-5.3

I have array converted into stdClass object like this,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [1339697186] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1403873546800880] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [quantity_request] => 2
                    [time_created] => 1339697190
                    [variant] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [0] => 1403873546800887
                        )

                )

        )

    [1339697196] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1403873546800880] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [quantity_request] => 1
                    [time_created] => 1339697196
                    [variant] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [0] => 1403889656952419
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So if I want to get `[quantity_request]` of each item, I will loop **twice** to get the answer,

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item) 
{
    foreach ($item as $code => $item) 
    {
        echo $item->quantity_request;
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to get the answer like this below **without** looping the object array twice?

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item) 
{
    # Get the product code of this item.
    $code = $cart->search_code($key);

    echo $item->$code->quantity_request;
}
```

error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...

I have a method in a class to get the code (sub key) from the content of the object array.

```
public function search_code($key)
{
        # Get this item.
        $item = $this->content[$key];

        # Get this item's sub key, which is the code of the product.
        $subkeys = array_keys($item);

        # Get the first item from the array.
        $code = $subkeys[0];

        # Return the sub key which is the code of the product.
        return $code;
}
```

Comment: Note: your use of two $item variables in the double foreach is going to cause problems.

Comment: @ben: I'm not sure it will cause problems, I think the shadowing will perform as intended.  But I agree that its confusing / unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that I know of :

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item) 
{
    $array = (object) array_shift($item);

    echo $array->quantity_request.'<br />';
}
```

I hope I answer your question, didn't understand well at 100%.

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$items = (object) array(
    1339697186 => array(1403873546800880 => array('quantity_request' => 2)),
    1339697187 => array(1403873546800880 => array('quantity_request' => 3)),
    1339697188 => array(1403873546800880 => array('quantity_request' => 4))
);

foreach ($items as $key => $item) 
{
    $array = (object) array_shift($item);

    echo $array->quantity_request.'<br />';
}
?>

// Results :
2<br />3<br />4<br />
```

Comment: Just a note: This would work of each top-level object had exactly one second-level object (as his posted `print_r`s suggest).  But if he had multiple second-level objects per top-level object, it would skip some whereas his two-loop solution would not.

Comment: @jedwards Yes, I know. But in the example I only saw one entry on the second level, so I guessed... let's see his answer.

Comment: THanks David Bélanger for the answer. I think it works with your answer. Thanks!